# Fetching Skype chat logs in blackberry via code

Tags: blackberry, chat, skype

I am developing a blackberry application, in that I have to fetch **Skype chat logs**. I have googled a lot on this topic, but didn't find any related info.  Could any one tell me how to fetch **Skype** logs(Chat history) via code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible as this would be a third party application asking for information from another third party application.  Each application is sand boxed and therefore unable to retrieve information outside of their verticals unless it is released, example like using the shared folder.

Hope that helps!
WiLL

Comment: BlackBerry OS doesn't do sandboxing.